# AccuRev move folder to own depot keeping history

Tags: jenkins, accurev

One of folders in my depot need to be moved to its own depot with keeping commit history.
I need this to separate jenkins builds.

Is it possible to do this keeping history, not creating new baseline?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alex

Keeping history is not possible if you need to move a directory and its content from DepotA into DepotB.

A workaround would be to setup in DepotA a seperate stream for this directory, you can exclude all the other folders so you only see this one.  This way, you will retain your history.